# How to align the text from webpage in android web view?

Tags: android, webview

In my application i have one web view .I will loading a simple html page inside that it is working correctly .But the content of the web page is displaying without alignment I want to display the contents with justified alignment

Please any one give me idea for how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the `align=justify` HTML attribute (deprecated) or CSS `text-align:justify` in you web page?